# PyQt5: ImportError: No module named sip

Tags: python, pyqt5, sip

This has me completely bamboozled. I wanted to compile PyQt5. To do that I first need to compile and install sip. So I compiled and installed sip. Then I compiled and installed PyQt5. No problems so far. Then I tried it out.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sip
>>> import PyQt5
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sip
>>>
```

What??? I had to have sip installed to compile PyQt5. I had to have sip installed to import it. Why is it now telling me that there is "No module named sip?"

Comment: Why aren't you using the PyQt5 packages provided by your Linux distro? And why are you using Python2 with PyQt5? Also, did you read the [installation instructions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source) properly (esp. the note at the beginning)?

Comment: Because they didn't work. I had to recompile Qt to get what I was trying to compile to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with system packages (installed via apt), with a virtual env created with `--system-site-packages`, and I don't have it inside a proper virtual env. Python3.6, LinuxMint 19.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was inside (venv) running the python from the venv/bin

it cleared and found sip when I used usr/bin/python

(in my setup they were the same versions, please check you product and setup that the virtual py is not needed)